# React-Scripts can't build on Windows running WSL Ubuntu

Tags: reactjs, windows-subsystem-for-linux, react-scripts

My react scripts build stalls at

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Starting type checking and linting service...
Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit
(node:3580) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
(node:3580) DeprecationWarning: Pass resolveContext instead and use createInnerContext
(node:3580) DeprecationWarning: Resolver: The callback argument was splitted into resolveContext and callback.
(node:3580) DeprecationWarning: Resolver#doResolve: The type arguments (string) is now a hook argument (Hook). Pass a reference to the hook instead.
```

This is running in Ubuntu on Windows WSL. Weird thing is that it seems to be using almost no resources when doing the build.. w

Build command is `react-app-rewired build --scripts-version react-scripts-ts`

This has been working fine, however a collegue has added some lazy loading in components and I think this may be the culript. It's building fine for him but not for me and another.

How can I add logging to this build to find where it gets stuck?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue during webpack 4 upgrade, so i have updated        **"tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",**
and then the deprecation warning disappeared, so it works for me. Please try, it may be it also removes your warning because these are related to webpack config warnings.